# java -jar with cf -e not working on Java 14

Tags: java, jar, javac

I'm playing around with `javac` + `java` + `java -jar` to get more involved with modules.

I'm using latest JDK 14.

I have this simple class:

```
package defaultpackage;
public class Main{
    public static final void main(final String args[]){
        System.out.println("HI WITH: "+java.util.Arrays.toString(args));
    }
}
```

I create the directories without problems:

```
javac -d . Main.java
```

Later on I can create the jar file playing mixing some values like this:

```
jar --create --file Jar.jar -e defaultpackage.Main defaultpackage
jar -cfe Jar.jar defaultpackage.Main defaultpackage
jar cfe Jar.jar defaultpackage.Main defaultpackage
```

They all create the jar with the class in the manifest file and I could run it with this simple command:

```
java -jar Jar.jar
```

But I could not this command to work is a slightly different of the previous perhaps this couldn't be mixed but i thought it could:

```
jar -cf Jar.jar -e defaultpackage.Main defaultpackage
```

I'm trying to said well create the Jar.jar file with the entry point `defaultpackage.Main`

But states.

```
jar -cf Jar.jar -e defaultpackage.Main defaultpackage
-e : no such file or directory
defaultpackage.Main : no such file or directory
```

I have try this as well but with the same response:

```
jar -cf Jar.jar defaultpackage -e defaultpackage.Main
```

And:

```
jar -cf Jar.jar -e defaultpackage/Main.class defaultpackage
```

But also with the same response.

How can I make this command to work? I could not mix `-cf` plus `-e`?

Comment: “I could not mix `-cf` plus `-e`?”  Correct.  The options are somewhat like those of tar, but not exactly like tar.  You cannot use both combined letters and separate option letters.

Comment: got it mate please post it as answer.

Comment: @VGR By the way what is tar? mate The 1 thing it comes to my mind to that word is George Brett. :( hehe

Comment: @LinuxServer: please do not bold all sentences in a question. That is less readable, not more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could not mix `-cf` plus `-e`?

Correct.  The options are somewhat like those of the venerable Unix [tar](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) command, but not exactly the same.  You cannot use both combined letters and separate option letters.